# How to use Select2 with Reactjs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jquery-select2, react-select

I have dependent fields like this

```
    <List>
     <select>
      <option></option>
      <option></option>
     </select>
     <select>
      <option></option>
      <option></option>
     </select>
     <input />
   </List>
```

If I had 5 `<List/>` components.How do I add [Select2](https://select2.github.io/) to each component.I googled online.But couldn't find any working solution.

> Code below for **[react-select](https://github.com/JedWatson/react-select)**.Getting error **TypeError: event.target is undefined**.

```
var React = require('react');
var ReactDOM = require('react-dom');
var Select = require('react-select');

var Page = React.createClass({

    getInitialState: function () {
        return {
            firstValue: ''
        }
    },

    handleFirstLevelChange : function (event) {
        this.setState({
            firstValue: event.target.value
        });
    },
    render : function(){

        var options = [
            { value: '', label: 'Select an option' },
            { value: 'one', label: 'One' },
            { value: 'two', label: 'Two' }
        ];

        return (<Select
            value={this.state.firstValue}
            options={options}
            onChange={this.handleFirstLevelChange}
            />)
    }
});

ReactDOM.render(<Page />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Comment: I tried adding select2 in the html page and used this snippet.But It changed only the first select element.The dependent select fields were unchanged.
<script type="text/javascript">
  $('select').select2();
</script>

Comment: This is useful for wrapping jQuery libs in React, in general: https://github.com/ryanflorence/react-training/blob/gh-pages/lessons/05-wrapping-dom-libs.md

Answer (score 19):

We are using [this wrapper](https://github.com/rkit/react-select2-wrapper), but there are too many problems around it.

First of all, you can't test code where it is used in NodeJS, because of [this issue](https://github.com/select2/select2/issues/3282).
Secondly we had problems with initialization of various select2 components via `defaultValue` parameter. Only one (randomly) of these elements was initalized.

Therefore we going to dump it and replace with `react-select` soon.

EDIT: We replaced `react-select2-wrapper` with `react-select`. It works great for us.

Comment: even react-select has issues.I can't set the state.If I try to set the state the dropdown doesn't close.

Comment: Hmm not sure. We didn't  try it so far. It suppose to be very configurable. Isn't there some flag in docs?

Comment: <Select
            value={this.state.firstValue}
            options={options}
            onChange={this.handleFirstLevelChange} />
    handleFirstLevelChange : function (event) {
        this.setState({
            firstValue: event.target.value
        });
    }

I get TypeError: event.target is undefined

Comment: getting an error TypeError: event.target is undefined

Comment: added detail to my question.I dont know why I get the TypeError: event.target is undefined error

Comment: It seems to me that handleFirstLevelChange should be bound to this: this.handleFirstLevelChange.bind(this).

Comment: I was also having an issue with `defaultValue` and it turns out that it's supposed to be sent in as an attribute of Select2 rather than an option (i.e. `<Select2 defaultValue={value} options={select2opts} />`

Comment: I recommend switching to `react-select`. Not a single problem with that library.

Comment: @luboskrnac: react-select might be good but not perfect. One of the biggest problem I see with that package is that you have no support for optgroups . Plus, the idea of delegating an onchange event to every control being mandory for the value to actually change in the dropdown is something i believe is not very friendly in terms of performance.

Comment: "Not a single problem"? 1,202 open issues at https://github.com/JedWatson/react-select/issues I've had nothing but problems.

Answer (score 12):

If you're using `refs` [[docs]](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/more-about-refs.html), you can access the node via its `refs` attribute in the `componentDidMount` function and pass that to `select2()` :

```
var Select = React.createClass({
  handleChange: function () {
    this.prop.onChange(
      this.refs.myRef.value
    );
  },

  componentDidMount: function () {
    // Call select2 on your node
    var self = this;
    var node = this.refs.myRef; // or this.refs['myRef']
    $(node)
      .select2({...})
      .on('change', function() {
        // this ensures the change via select2 triggers 
        // the state change for your component 
        self.handleChange();
      });
  },

  render: function () {
    return (
      <select 
        ref="myRef"
        onChange={this.handleChange}>
        // {options}
      </select>
    );
  }
});
```

I don't believe this is the "React way," but this may help if you don't want to use `react-select` or some other tool.

Answer (score 9):

Since you're using React, you'd be better off looking for React components rather than jQuery plugins.  You can use for eaxmple [`react-select`](http://jedwatson.github.io/react-select/), which is pretty similar to Select2.

Comment: But I need a solution for Select2 because I am currently using it my application.

Comment: @Vishwasraj did you get the solution im breaking my head for this :(

Comment: @Vikram no solution found.changed to materialize css library.[link](http://materializecss.com/) to library

Comment: @Vishwasraj shit it will be so difficult to any other developer taking over this project becoz the rest of the modules are written on JQuery

Comment: @Vikram yes...rewriting select2 library from stratch to make it work for react framework is the only possible solution.

Answer (score 1):

Simple wrapper.

Add select2 js + css on index.html, write wrapper over select input

```
function renderOptions(option_items) {
    if(option_items) {
        return Object.entries(option_items).map(function (item) {
            return <option key={item[0]} value={item[0]}>{item[1]}</option>
        })
    }
}

class Select2Input extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.ref_input = React.createRef()
    }

    /**
    * Add select2 bind and send onChange manually
    */
    componentDidMount() {
        const self = this

        $(self.ref_input.current).select2({
            tags: true,
        }).on('change', function(event) {
            var value = $(event.currentTarget).val()
            if(self.props.multiple === true) {
                value = List(value)
            }
            self.props.onChange(self.props.name, value)
        })
    }

    /**
    * Emit change event for reload select2 if options has change
    */
    componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
        if(prevProps.option_items !== this.props.option_items) {
            $(this.ref_input.current).change()
        }
    }

    render() {
        return <select className="form-control"
                    multiple={this.props.multiple}
                    name={this.props.name}
                    value={this.props.value}
                    disabled={this.props.disabled}
                    ref={this.ref_input}>
                            {renderOptions(this.props.option_items)}
            </select>
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are just using jquery and select2 in a react application, you can simply link the cdn for Jquery and select2 in public/index.html inside "head" tag.
Then in your src/components/component.js. You can use jquery select2 like this:

```js
constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            Provinces: [],
        };
        this.select2PX = this.select2PX.bind(this);
        // this.ApiTest = this.ApiTest.bind(this);
}

select2PX(){
        window.$(document).ready(function() {
            window.$('#phuong-xa').select2();
        });
}

componentDidMount(){
  this.select2PX();
}


render(){
   return (.... html);
}
```

Because you use the cdns in the public/.html file, you need to use window.$ to use jquery. It achieves the same thing as using select2 in a html file.