# Loading JS in React app

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, reactjs

I'm building a React based form, and I need to include the Select2 jQuery plugin to style the select elements.

How do I go about including JS in my React project? I understand you want to let React handle the DOM, but at the same time I still need to style certain elements?

I tried including the JS files in my index.html, but that just ran before the HTML had even executed.

I'm unable to use the Select2 module due to the way my options are being generated.

I've installed jQuery and Select2 at the top of my component like so...

```
import jquery from 'jquery';
import select2 from 'select2';
```

and then...

```
componentDidMount() {
  return(
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $('select').select2();
    })
  )
}
```

This doesn't run as it says $ is undefined. But I don't think I am doing this the right way anyhow.

Comment: You can run your jQuery commands in your Component's `componentDidMount()`

Comment: Are you calling your jQuery within componentDidUpdate of the component ?

Comment: You should be using react component like [react-select](http://jedwatson.github.io/react-select/) .

Comment: Use NPM to install Select2, and then `require` it in the relevant React class. You should then be able to call its startup method.

Comment: I've installed via NPM, added imported them into my component. How do I call them in componentDidMount()?

Comment: Change the import to `import $ from 'jquery'`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use Select2 with Reactjs?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35176400/how-to-use-select2-with-reactjs)

Answer (score 0):

Diogo Sgrillo helped me with the correct answer...

All I needed to do was change jquery to $.